# Remove duplicated articles if only one article exists

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel

I have a slider on the page, and if there are more than two articles in it, then it works as it should and looks like this

[image]

But when I have only one article, the article duplicates itself to the right and left (see image below). And I need to remove the scrolling if there is only one, how to remove the scroll arrows you can see above is clear, I did it (see below).

The only thing left is to remove these parts on the right and left.

[image]

Here is the slider code:

**php.blade**

```
<div class="section-wrapper section-padding">
    <div class="container">
        <h2 class="section-title general-recommend-title-main">You May also find interest in</h2>
    @if($articleCount > 1)
        <div id="navWrapper" class="general-nav">
            <div id="prevArrow" class="general-nav__arrow"> <img src="/img/arrow-left.svg" alt="arrow left icon"> </div>
            <div id="navText" class="general-nav__text"></div>
            <div id="nextArrow" class="general-nav__arrow"> <img src="/img/arrow-right.svg" alt="arrow right icon"> </div>
        </div>
    @endif
    </div>
    <div class="general-slider-wrapper">
        <div id="generalSlider" class="general-slider">
            <div id="generalSliderRow" class="general-slider-row">
                @foreach($article->article_recommendations as $article_recommend)
                <div class="general">
                    <div class="general-image d-none d-lg-block" style="background-image: url({{ $article_recommend->image_list }})"></div>
                    <div class="general-image d-lg-none" style="background-image: url({{ isset($article_recommend->image_list_mobile) ? $article_recommend->image_list_mobile : $article_recommend->image_list }})"></div>
                    <div class="general-recommend-title">{{ $article_recommend->title }}</div>
                    <div class="general-recommend-date-views">
                        <div class="general-recommend-img">
                            <svg width="20px" height="20px" viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"></svg>
                        </div>
                        <div class="general-recommend-date">{{ date('d F Y', strtotime($article_recommend->published_at)) }}</div>
                        <div class="general-recommend-img">
                            <svg width="20px" height="20px" viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"></svg>
                        </div>
                        <div class="general-recommend-views">{{ $article_recommend->getTotalViews() }} Views</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                @endforeach
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**js**

```
 // Slider
 const slider = document.getElementById('generalSlider');
 const sliderRow = document.getElementById('generalSliderRow');
 const slides = document.querySelectorAll('.general');
 const INTERVAL = 6000;
 let timer = null;
 
 initSlider(slider, sliderRow, slides);
 
 function initSlider(slider, sliderRow, slides) {
     const slidesLength = slides.length;
 
     let allowShift = true;
     const CLONES_COUNT = 1;
     let slideWidth = slider.offsetWidth;
     const firstSlide = slides[0];
 
     let currentOffset = -slideWidth * CLONES_COUNT;
     let currentIndex = 1;
 
     slides.forEach(slide => {
         slide.style.width = slideWidth + 'px';
     });
 
     const appendSlides = [];
     const prependSlides = [];
 
     for (let i = 1; i <= CLONES_COUNT; i++) {
         prependSlides.push(slides[slidesLength - i].cloneNode(true));
         appendSlides.push(slides[i - 1].cloneNode(true));
     }
 
     prependSlides.reverse().forEach(slide => {
         sliderRow.insertBefore(slide, firstSlide);
     });
 
     appendSlides.forEach(slide => {
         sliderRow.appendChild(slide);
     });
 
     sliderRow.style.width = (slideWidth * (slidesLength + CLONES_COUNT * 2)) + 'px';
     sliderRow.style.transform = `translateX(${currentOffset}px)`;
 
     document.querySelector(`.general:nth-child(${currentIndex + CLONES_COUNT})`).classList.add('active');
     document.getElementById('navText').innerHTML = `${currentIndex} of ${slidesLength}`;
 
     const prevArrow = document.getElementById('prevArrow');
     const nextArrow = document.getElementById('nextArrow');
 
     prevArrow.addEventListener('click', () => {
         shiftSlide(-1);
         stopAutoplay();
     });
 
     nextArrow.addEventListener('click', () => {
         shiftSlide(1);
         stopAutoplay();
     });
 
     sliderRow.addEventListener('transitionend', checkIndex);
     sliderRow.addEventListener('click', stopAutoplay);
 
     function shiftSlide(dir, action = null) {
         sliderRow.classList.add('shifting');
 
         if (action) {
             currentOffset = posInitial;
         }
 
         if (allowShift) {
             if (dir === 1) {
                 currentOffset -= slideWidth;
                 sliderRow.style.transform = `translateX(${currentOffset}px)`;
                 currentIndex++;
             } else if (dir === -1) {
                 currentOffset += slideWidth;
                 sliderRow.style.transform = `translateX(${currentOffset}px)`;
                 currentIndex--;
             }
 
             document.querySelector('.general.active').classList.remove('active');
             document.querySelector(`.general:nth-child(${currentIndex + CLONES_COUNT})`).classList.add('active');
         }
 
         allowShift = false;
     }
 
     function checkIndex (){
         sliderRow.classList.remove('shifting');
 
         if (currentIndex === 0) {
             currentOffset = (-slideWidth * CLONES_COUNT) + (-slideWidth * (slidesLength - 1));
             sliderRow.style.transform = `translateX(${currentOffset}px)`;
             currentIndex = slidesLength;
         }
 
         if (currentIndex > slidesLength) {
             currentOffset = -slideWidth * CLONES_COUNT;
             sliderRow.style.transform = `translateX(${currentOffset}px)`;
             currentIndex = 1;
         }
 
         document.getElementById('navText').innerHTML = `${currentIndex} of ${slidesLength}`;
         document.querySelector('.general.active').classList.remove('active');
         document.querySelector(`.general:nth-child(${currentIndex + CLONES_COUNT})`).classList.add('active');
 
         allowShift = true;
     }
 
     let posX1 = 0;
     let posX2 = 0;
     let posInitial;
     let posFinal;
     const threshold = 100;
 
     // sliderRow.onmousedown = dragStart;
     // sliderRow.addEventListener('touchstart', dragStart);
     // sliderRow.addEventListener('touchend', dragEnd);
     // sliderRow.addEventListener('touchmove', dragAction);
 
     function dragStart (e) {
         e = e || window.event;
         e.preventDefault();
         if (!allowShift) {
             return;
         }
         posInitial = currentOffset;
 
         if (e.type == 'touchstart') {
             posX1 = e.touches[0].clientX;
         } else {
             posX1 = e.clientX;
             document.onmouseup = dragEnd;
             document.onmousemove = dragAction;
         }
     }
 
     function dragAction (e) {
         e = e || window.event;
 
         if (e.type == 'touchmove') {
             posX2 = posX1 - e.touches[0].clientX;
             posX1 = e.touches[0].clientX;
         } else {
             posX2 = posX1 - e.clientX;
             posX1 = e.clientX;
         }
         currentOffset = currentOffset - posX2;
         sliderRow.style.transform = `translateX(${currentOffset}px)`;
     }
 
     function dragEnd (e) {
         posFinal = currentOffset;
         if (posFinal - posInitial < -threshold) {
             shiftSlide(1, 'drag');
         } else if (posFinal - posInitial > threshold) {
             shiftSlide(-1, 'drag');
         } else {
             currentOffset = posInitial;
             sliderRow.style.transform = `translateX(${currentOffset}px)`;
         }
 
         document.onmouseup = null;
         document.onmousemove = null;
     }
 
     window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
         resizeSlider();
     })
 
     function resizeSlider() {
         const newSlideWidth = slider.offsetWidth;
 
         if (newSlideWidth === slideWidth) return;
 
         slideWidth = newSlideWidth;
 
         document.querySelectorAll('.general').forEach(slide => {
             slide.style.width = slideWidth + 'px';
         });
 
         currentOffset = (-slideWidth * CLONES_COUNT) + (-slideWidth * (currentIndex - 1));
 
         sliderRow.style.width = (slideWidth * (slidesLength + CLONES_COUNT * 2)) + 'px';
         sliderRow.style.transform = `translateX(${currentOffset}px)`;
     }
 
     function startAutoplay() {
         timer = setInterval(() => {
             shiftSlide(1);
         }, INTERVAL)
     }
 
     function stopAutoplay() {
         clearInterval(timer);
         timer = null;
     }
 
     startAutoplay();
 }
```

Comment: Have you tried something to fix it?

Comment: @Allart Yes, I tried to simply disable the slider if there are less than 2 articles `if (slidesLength < 2) {
         return false;
     }` 
But then this single slide is not displayed correctly

Comment: My approach would probably be: finding the scrolling functionality, understand how it works and figure out how to disable it. I think your biggest issue here is that you don't understand your code. It's fine if you copy code or use library's and stuff, but try to at least figure out how it works. Line for line. And I dont mean the whole library its lines, but the code you actually use, like shown in your question for example. Understanding it prevents you from getting alot of these questions. Probably also trains you how to debug code.

Comment: @Allart cloneNode() is what these pieces are on the right and left, but if you remove this, then again the entire slide is displayed incorrectly, it would be possible to find an opportunity to simply hide it all

Comment: And all, all you need to do is put `const CLONES_COUNT = 0;` if there are less than 2 slides

Comment: @Allart thanks for the advice, in the future I will do this :)

Comment: Well maybe you can hide them with css then. Use your if statement above and set your right and left article visible in your image to display: none;. You can do this in js. Not sure if scrolling will be gone at such point. Also still wouldn't recommend this "fix". I mean, if there is something creating these right and left articles, there must be a way to stop it from doing so.

Comment: @Allart I almost at the very beginning have `const CLONES_COUNT = 1;` , 
if 0 then one slide will be displayed as it should, if 1 then all the others will work as it should, the only thing you need to figure out how to make this comparison

Comment: @Allart Something like that `const CLONES_COUNT;
if (slidesLength < 2) { CLONES_COUNT = 0;  } else { CLONES_COUNT = 1; }` but for me now this is complete nonsense, since `const CLONES_COUNT` must have some meaning

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239272/discussion-between-allart-and-chu).

Comment: damn, instead of `const`, you can just use `let`, and everything will work :)